# Unique user identification

Tags: php, browser, system, security

I am working on a webby, which would need **unique** user identification like IP/MAC address. But there is a slight problem with it. Our company is a part of financial group under a bank. Which means they have strict firewall policy and everything that comes trough it comes as the same internal IP, also it will filter some additional information about the user, which I cant use as its again their security policy. Site works with loans, that people can make. Finance department would like to make sure, that one user wont send more 30 requests in a small period of time, etc. etc.

Thus I need to make sure, that the identificator I use is reliable and hard to fake or at least has some sort of consistency AND wont bother user with any additional clicks (ActiveX, installing 3rd party stuff, etc.). Cookies, can be turned off or deleted, IPs can be changed (VPN, dynamic IPs).

Preferably PHP or JS, though JAVA/python, could be used as well. I tried internet, but cant get a straight answer on this.

Any ideas are highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: There is no way that I'm aware of to do what you want reliably against somebody that wants to get around it.  For the average user however, simply requiring a user account with a unique email associated is a good step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do users log in to the site?  If so, just restrict activity by user account.

Otherwise, there is no effective way to prevent anonymous activity by a determined opponent.

Comment: I can't possibly imagine why this site won't have a logon? If the idea is to more tightly link users to activities then you can look at deploying client-end certificates to each users' machine. It's worthwhile to look at only if serious money is involved with your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie to store an unique identifier and generate a security token (some sort of hash, like an Sha-512 hash combining some unique user information).

If you want to be able to use this approach even if cookies are disabled, you can use a hidden field and set there what could be in the cookie, and get the session identifier and security token back to the server after every post-back.

So, you only need to take care about using some sort of "salt" in your hashing mechanism so an external program, add-in or hack wouldn't be able to crack your hashed/encrypted information.

Comment: That will work for the average user, but there's nothing preventing a smart user from falsifying cookie data.

Comment: You're wrong :D Cookie data is hashed using a salt or salts that are only known by the server, meaning that's impossible - only if someone hacks the web server - to steal salts and generate valid hashes. Keep in mind that some session service, server, will be storing the session in some table or other storage, and the hashed version sent to the client is hashed with the salt(s), so, again, the server-side stored version of hashes are impossible to reproduce in the client-side without such salt(s).

Comment: Problem with this approach is, I need the most reliable identifier, which I can use in between salts :) Generating salts, hashes, etc. is not a problem.

Comment: But, sadly, web browser won't send you an actual IP, but the proxy one, or like your case, same for all... You don't really have an "unique" information.  I've been looking for the same thing some time ago, and no way. For example, you can't know the MAC address of clients, which would be a good unique identifier, if not the best. Server, as I suggested you, is the responsible of setting that "unique identifier" to clients...

Comment: @Matías even if browser would, I doubt you'll find an IP address like 10.10.0.10 whatever useful

Comment: @Col Yeah, that's why I pointed a MAC would be nice, but because proxies, firewalls, it'd useless to have a router MAC (f.e.).

Comment: @Matías yes you could use a hashed cookie, but the user could just delete it and request a new one.  Either the server generates and hands out new cookies (which doesn't solve the problem), or the user has to authenticate to get a cookie.  If you have to authenticate anyway, just give the user a session ID in the cookie and handle it the Right way: server-side user monitoring.

Comment: @Justin I believe no one caught my suggestion. I was believing that you all understood I was referring to having a hashed cookie of "???" (the thing I explained in my answer) and, obviously, such session, bound to some user account... But, no way! haha, the best thing is who did the question got an answer. This is the point of Stackoverflow, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no users on the internet. Only computers...

Comment: In fact, there are no computers. Only packets.